# Find the maximum number of occurrences of a field in a collection?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I was looking at the site, and although it is silly I did not find the solution.
Having the following example collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b61d710bb0d4d1e5191fe8c"),
    "a" : [ 
        "#asd", 
        "#qwerty", 
        "#special"
    ],
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b61d69bbb0d4d1e5191fe8b"),
    "a" : [ 
        "#pretty",
    ],
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b61d710bb0d4d1e5191fe8d"),
    "a" : [ 
        "#asd", 
        "#noun", 
        "#rework"
    ],
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b61d710bb0d4d1e5191fe8e"),
    "a" : [ 
        "#asd"
    ]
}
```

How can I get the string with the most occurrences within a?
Thanks for the help.
Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query.

[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to reduce the array into individual string followed by [`$sortbyCount`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortByCount/) to group and count the occurrences and sort the occurrences in descending order.

[`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to get the value with most occurrences.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$a"},
  {"$sortByCount":"$a"},
  {"$limit":1}
])
```